# I am looking for REST api client

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using react and I am looking for the best rest client library. I am looking for a library that will allow me to define all my endpoints and will export a methods for those endpoints.
I really like angular-resource but I can't find port for non-angular usage.
Any recommendations?

Comment: I wish that you had given a URL for `angular-resource`. I am intrigued, but can't find it

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked over at Stack Overflow. Here is a link to it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921942/javascript-rest-client

As a side note, I have used angularJS's $resource and $http both, and they both work well - though I wouldn't use just those two pieces of Angular - I'd use them if I was using Angular to build a larger single page application.